# Changelog creation based on package.json version (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, git, changelog

So I bump up   "version": "1.0.2"   in package.json in my node app for every release ( there åre many git commits,Merges that go in between 1.0.1 to 1.0.2 for e.g.)
I tried couple of changelog generators(that's on npm ,github- https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-changelog,https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-changelog) but none of them seem to create changelog with git commit messages grouped by the version #.